# Error installing snap ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I get this error when try to install `snapd` from terminal:

```
Selecting previously unselected package squashfs-tools.
(Reading database ... 265122 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../squashfs-tools_1%3a4.3-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking squashfs-tools (1:4.3-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ubuntu-core-launcher.
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-core-launcher_1.0.27_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-core-launcher (1.0.27) ...
Preparing to unpack .../archives/snapd_2.0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.0.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/snap.1.gz', which is also in package snap 2013-11-29-1ubuntu2
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't use the snap install at all. Please help. I don't want to reinstall my laptop. :(

Comment: It looks like the packages `snap` and `snapd` conflict with each other. Are you sure you need both?

Comment: Are they meant to be installed at the same time? Where did you get them?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't have the [snap](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/snap) [image: Install xenial/snap] package installed at the same time as the [snapd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/snapd) [image: Install xenial/snapd] package. In fact, I think the fact that apt didn't warn you about this is a bug in our packaging. Sorry. (this is [bug 1571989](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1571989))

So, to fix your issue: `sudo apt install snapd snap-` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to leave this answer here for anybody getting this during installation of 16.04 --- see this post:

[Installation fails due to snapd trying to overwrite a package from snap-confine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893399/ubuntu-16-04-dual-boot-installation-fails-because-of-snap/893497#893497)

**Related Question / Solution for those getting this error during installation: Unplug your internet connection / disable wifi.**

Quick fix is to have no active connection during installation.

This is a known bug that is being caused by a package that is downloaded using aptitude. (See link below.) To make sure you don't download the package, the only way to do this is to disable your internet connection, and in my case, unplug the ethernet cable during installation.

See bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1673247.